# React native splash screen doesn't work on react-native 0.71+

Tags: android, ios, react-native, splash-screen

By using [Splash screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) docs, it is not possible to make disappear the splash screen. the app got stuck behind showing the splash screen.

iOS native codes:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"ttttapp";
  
 [RNSplashScreen show];

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Android native codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
    org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen.show(this, true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the iOS `AppDelegate.m` file it should be like the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{  
  self.moduleName = @"ProjectName";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
  
  bool didFinish=[super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  
  [RNSplashScreen show];  // here
  return didFinish;
}
```

On the Android `MainActivity.java` file should be like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  SplashScreen.show(this);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Reference: [issue#606](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/606)

Answer (score 2):

I fix this by modifying my ApDelegate.mm file
from

```js
   // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
 [RNSplashScreen show]; 
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
 
}
```

to

```js
 self.initialProps = @{};
  [super application: applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  [RNSplashScreen show]; 
  return YES;
```

Comment: is it safe to use? because without having an idea of what `[super application: applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];` does, it can break the functionality.